# Remove array from two dimensional array if it has an element

Tags: python, list

I have something like this:

input: `[['5', '-1'], ['3', '5'], ['6', '3'], ['7', '3']]` and the code is `'5'`. Output should be: `[['6', '3'], ['7', '3']]`. So all elements that had a code were removed. I've tried doing something like this:

```
parent_ids =  [['5', '-1'], ['3', '5'], ['6', '3'], ['7', '3']]
print(parent_ids)

code = '5'

for parent_id in parent_ids:
    print(parent_id)

    for sublist in parent_id:
        if code in sublist:
            parent_ids.remove(parent_id)
```

But I get `[['3', '5'], ['6', '3'], ['7', '3']]`  which is not 100% correct, it removed only 1 element

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
parent_ids =  [['5', '-1'], ['3', '5'], ['6', '3'], ['7', '3']]
code = '5'
parent_ids = [i for i in parent_ids if not code in i]
```

**Output** :

```
[['6', '3'], ['7', '3']]
```